# Macro VBA Excel sum by Group

Tags: excel, vba

I know in Excel we can use pivot table, but I just want to make a button to sum a group by Vendor, this is the illustrate of my table in Excel:

[image]

I just want to sum Amount grouping by Vendor in new column and add 1 column to proof that column has a value bigger than 2,550,000.

Like this result when I hit a button "RUN":

[image]

I need using macro because we have dynamic data from pivot table (SSAS) and always change everyday, so I have to make sure the new column in this excel to provide the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following formula can be used to sum the D column group by A column.

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",SUMIF(A:A,A2,D:D))
```

Then you can put the condition in F column.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D2),IF(D2>255000,TRUE,FALSE),"")
```

And you can use the following VBA code to write the above formula:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Condition As Variant
    Dim AVal As Variant
    For i = 1 To 10 'replace 10 with last row count
         Condition = "A" & i & "=A" & i - 1
         AVal = "A" & i
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Formula = "=IF(" & Condition & ","""",SUMIF(A:A," & AVal & ",D:D))"
         DVal = "D" & i
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(" & DVal & "),IF(" & DVal & ">255000,TRUE,FALSE),"""")"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: but i need the code put in macro not only formula

Comment: I think it would be better to use formula.

Comment: i need using macro because we have dynamic data from pivot table (SSAS) and always change everyday, so i have to make sure the  new column in this excel to provide the data

Comment: updated the answer